# sqlite3_prepare_v2 != SQLITE_OK

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanna ask about my function below.
It print NOT AVAILABLE when I call this function.
Could you help me please??

```
    static sqlite3 *database = nil;
    static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

    - (BOOL) findNews:(NSString *)caption{   
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"CAPTION ID : %@", caption);
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM dbase WHERE CONTENT_ID = \"%@\"", caption];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                return YES;
            }
            else{
                return NO;
            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: use single quate instead of double quate for string type data in your query...

Comment: For prepareStatement we use binding variables.So instead of providing %@, give ?, and bind that ? with value later.Since those are pre complied statements.

Comment: @NuzhatZari could you explain more specifics to me??

Comment: You can refer following tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

Comment: @NuzhatZari: There is no need of using binding variable. His query and code is correct. Possibly there will be no such table in his database or there will be no data for that particular contentID etc

Comment: could you give me the example about sqlite db in ios?

Answer (score 7):

There are some reason for due to which the sqlite3_prepare_v2 != SQLITE_OK :

1. The table may not present into the database.
2. Wrong query statement .
3. Wrong column name into the query statement.

You can find the exact problem using error statement by putting following in else:

```
 NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database))
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 [open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html). "If the filename is an empty string, then a private, temporary on-disk database will be created. This private database will be automatically deleted as soon as the database connection is closed."

So the sqlite3_open will return SQLITE_OK, if the data base not copied into Documents directory. You should copy the data into Bundle and copy this data base to Documents directory.

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{

    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success) return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

}
```